# When the user logs in, logout button must show, but it's not showing instantly. Why is it happening?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { compose } from "redux"


class Header extends Component {

    handleLogout = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        localStorage.clear()
        this.props.history.push("/")
    }

    render() {
        // const token = this.props.authReducer.user && this.props.authReducer.user.user.token 
        return (
            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <div>
                    App
                </div>
                <div>
                    {
                        localStorage.token ?
                            <div>
                                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                                <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
                                <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
                                <button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                            </div>
                            :
                            <div>
                                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                                <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
                                <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
                            </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
    return store
}


export default compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(Header);
```

After logging in, it's taking some time to get the response back and thus the token in localStorage, that's why I'm getting this, no? I have to refresh once to get it to display on the Header.

Also, I've tried to use redux store but after refreshing, redux store doesn't persist.

Comment: You should use state instead of localstorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use state values also for checking loggout, See my sample below

```
{ ( (localStorage.token === '') || (this.state.loggedIn === false)  )?
    <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
        <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
    </div>    
    :
    <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to    ="/login">Sign in</Link>
        <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
        <button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
    </div>
}
```

Function I have modifed as given below

```
handleLogout = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({loggedIn : false });
    this.props.history.push("/");
}
```

Comment: I've been using redux store to keep the state. Is it a better idea to keep local state?

Comment: For getting instant changes, you need to use local state. You can keep redux storage same as it is. But use local state to show/ hide instance changes to your templates

Comment: @metalHeadDev you can also use the store and safe loggedIn state in store. Than you would get your state like `this.props.loggedIn`

Comment: @Antoni but that would vanish on refresh? No?

Comment: This would be rerender the component because props changes and a reload of the page would be not required.

Comment: Ohhh I knew what your real problem is search after `persistent redux store` and your issues will be gone. If you use persistent redux store all your values which will be safe in the store will be not deleted after refresh. @metalHeadDev

Comment: This is not working. Now, nothing's happening, not even the logout button is showing up.

Comment: @metalHeadDev try only this (this.state.loggedIn === false) as condition

Comment: We're not setting loggedIn to true anywhere?

Comment: After login you need to set state value loggedIn to true , I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

It does not work instantly because a React component do not get the changes instantly from `localstorage` you could use state instead.

```
....

class Header extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: false }
  componentDidMount () {
    if(localStorage.token) {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
    }
  }

  handleLogout = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    localStorage.clear()
    this.setState({ loggedIn: false })
    this.props.history.push("/")
  }

  render() {
        const { loggedIn } = this.state
        return (
            <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <div>
                    App
                </div>
                <div>
                    {
                        loggedIn ?
                            <div>
                                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                                <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
                                <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
                                <button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
                            </div>
                            :
                            <div>
                                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                                <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
                                <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
                            </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleLogout = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({
    loggedIn : false
 },()=>this.props.history.push("/"));
```

this.setState does not update state instantly. So any function which you want to call after setting state should be as callback. So this should work in your case.

Comment: And I would say use state instead of just checking localStorage. So use loggedIn property to check what to render.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to rerender your component . So a re-render can only be triggered if a component's state has changed. The state can change from a props change, or from a direct setState change. The component gets the updated state and React decides if it should re-render the component. 
Therefore either you can store the details like for login you can store in state or in props. So in your case rest all details could be store in local storage. Just set a flag isLogged in to true / false depending and accordingly you can show the button.

Note: Don't misunderstand and delete all the details from local storage or cookies as on page refresh state is lost